# setjmp and longjmp implementation

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, clang++

basically my problem in short is my implementation for setjmp and longjmp 
doesn't work. the reason why i'm asking in this form not in (code review) is that i'm new to assembly i've little background and still learning but still not sure about the code (please read until the end).

first i'v executed the code on two platforms with three different compilers 
and that's the reason why i'm sure that i'm doing something wrong with the assembler.

platforms: mac OS 10.12.5 x86_64 , ubuntu linux x86
compilers: Apple LLVM clang 8.0.0 x86_x64 ,clang 3.9.1 x86_x64 ,gcc 6.3 x86

i've compiled the code in 32bit mode on all platforms so the generated machine code on linux and mac with this example is 32bit.

the code i will post here is the was compiled under Apple clang with no optimization using -m32 flag to generate 32bit machine code

```
 #include <cstdio>


typedef unsigned long jmp_buf[6];


int Setjmp(jmp_buf var){
     __asm__(
             "    mov -4(%ebp), %eax     # get pointer to jmp_buf, passed as argument on stack\n"
             "    mov    %ebx, (%eax)   # jmp_buf[0] = ebx\n"
             "    mov    %esi, 4(%eax)  # jmp_buf[1] = esi\n"
             "    mov    %edi, 8(%eax)  # jmp_buf[2] = edi\n"
             "    mov    %ebp, 12(%eax) # jmp_buf[3] = ebp\n"
             "    lea   4(%esp), %ecx     # get previous value of esp, before call\n"
             "    mov    %ecx, 16(%eax) # jmp_buf[4] = esp before call\n"
             "    mov  (%esp), %ecx     # get saved caller eip from top of stack\n"
             "    mov    %ecx, 20(%eax) #jmp_buf[5] = saved eip\n"
             "    xor    %eax, %eax     #eax = 0\n"
     );

    return 0;
}

void Longjmp(jmp_buf var,int m){
    __asm__("    mov  -4(%ebp),%edx # get pointer to jmp_buf, passed as argument 1 on stack\n"
            "    mov  -8(%ebp),%eax #get int val in eax, passed as argument 2 on stack\n"
            "    test    %eax,%eax # is int val == 0?\n"
            "    jnz 1f\n"
            "    inc     %eax      # if so, eax++\n"
            "1:\n"
            "    mov   (%edx),%ebx # ebx = jmp_buf[0]\n"
            "    mov  4(%edx),%esi # esi = jmp_buf[1]\n"
            "    mov  8(%edx),%edi #edi = jmp_buf[2]\n"
            "    mov 12(%edx),%ebp # ebp = jmp_buf[3]\n"
            "    mov 16(%edx),%ecx # ecx = jmp_buf[4]\n"
            "    mov     %ecx,%esp # esp = ecx\n"
            "    mov 20(%edx),%ecx # ecx = jmp_buf[5]\n"
            "    jmp *%ecx         # eip = ecx");
}



void fancy_func(jmp_buf env);

int main() {
    jmp_buf env;
    int ret = Setjmp(env);
    if (ret == 0) {
        puts("just returning from setjmp!");
        fancy_func(env);
    } else {
        puts("now returning from longjmp and exiting!");
    }

}

void fancy_func(jmp_buf env) {
    puts("doing fancy stuff");
    Longjmp(env, 1);
}
```

i was following this tutorial : http://vmresu.me/blog/2016/02/09/lets-understand-setjmp-slash-longjmp/

Note: I've debugged the source code the problem comes from the:

```
 jmp *%ecx
```

but i think the problem is with setjmp and the way i'm storing the context 
and specially that line:

```
 lea   4(%esp), %ecx     # get previous value of esp, before call\n"
```

which is also the part of the code that i'm not getting it.

i'm also aware of the code that was generated by my compiler for calling and cleaning the stack of setjmp and longjmp and the calling convention that was used (CDECL) in my case.

much thanks for any help .

Comment: C++ is not C is not C++! And that might be your problem. Why do you want to use them at all? Just don't. In C++, use exceptions, `setjmp` etc are some of the more problematic C legacies (when using C++) and they should be used with caution and.sparesly in C already.

Comment: Oh, and: read [ask] and follow the advice.

Comment: Why are you programming in inline assembly? The stack layout is basically unpredictable from within inline assembly, you can't just assume that the compiler pushes the base pointer or anything like that.

Comment: I want them for Coroutines that's why i've tagged C and C++

Comment: @jacky Then why don't you use the `setjmp` implementation in the libc?

Comment: @fuz I'm just curios about the real world implementation of those functions I've looked in libstdC++ but still can't get the some part of the code because of my assembly knowledge

Comment: @jacky I mean, that's fine, but please just write normal assembly instead of inline assembly. Inline assembly is a really easy way to shoot yourself into your foot because the compiler can change so many things.

Comment: @fuz you're right I actually don't write inline assembly in my code but why I'm using it here because it's the only way to do context switch any way using godbolt compiler explorer the compiler doesn't edit any part of the assembly code at least with no optimization on .

Comment: @jacky Why don't you use the C compiler installed on your system? You are just making things a lot more difficult for yourself. Note that when writing assembly, it actually doesn't matter what C compiler you use, so I really don't understand why you'd want to use godbolt.

Comment: @fuz I've mentioned that I've used three compilers on two different machines I took a look at the generated assembly by the compilers on my machine and on godbolt they're identical . look I just want to know the mistake I'm making in my code that's my big problem . any way thanks

Comment: @jacky The mistake is that what you do can't work in this manner. I mean, yeah, you can make it accidentally work by fumbling around until the stack layout is just right, but one option change and it breaks again. This code is unfixable in the way you wrote it. If you would use plain assembly, then I could surely tell you what the problem is, because then it's actually possibly to make this work in a reasonable manner.

Comment: @fuz  so if I get it right the implementation of setjmp and longjmp is back for the ABI developers of the compiler and stander library because they can let the code works in the right manner in any place ?

Comment: @jacky No. What I am trying to say is that just must stop using inline assembly for this purpose because the compiler chooses a stack layout in a basically unpredictable manner. Write this in pure assembly and we can talk. I am not even going to try and guess how the compiler chose to lay out the stack in your case, that would be a waste of time.

Comment: @jacky - A new option just arrived [Clang 5.0 has coroutines built into the compiler](http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#major-new-features). Now you don't *have to* hack it yourself.

Comment: @BoPersson thanks for the comment . Actually I've used boost.Coroutines before. the question was just out of curiosity and again thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many problems with this. As fuz said, you should not use inline assembly like this. Use separate asm file, or at least constraints and better not rely on a particular stack layout.

Anyway you got the offsets wrong, arguments are at **positive** offset from `ebp` not negative, with first being `8(%ebp)`. Also you got the return address wrong, it's at `4(%esp)` since `(%esp)` is the saved `ebp`. Furthermore, since the function prologue saved `ebp` you are not saving the caller's `ebp` but a copy of `esp`.

The fixed version (still only works in 32-bit mode for calling conventions with stack args):

See the resulting asm for the whole function [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5AQCeAB0xYAZgGoRLQXmAslqhqjaqqAW3kB9AEYjlHAKw8AbPYAiHAMx8ADAEEOvgHoA1VR5AjwTPAAvTAhuLhZUAFpUSIIk5WImE0wk%2BVQ8FgJMYniASlV0VExBFjAZVUFMTBNVIlUAdxIAa38fIM7MRvCGBkrDeoJVYEwpplVM7Nz8wqmNBhrBQYWSCVUkgHkvHeI2hCHlDWRww07CBBCwiOjYrzK%2B83MmAgJiPGtip8oIlCgxCphSKpEsgDLpIcRZmJNOYCB08BJIaFwpEYhA3pinjjYvFEik0hksjk8gUiiVymV3r5VqoAMqzUzyahmKw2VQANyYxHeAHZvD5VBLVAMEWCaiEWGchmgzHgNqd2iYmN0hvNBAQmMhuhSln1JVLgpZMMgmCImoN6gj1FojKDwaomIJWoUtFh3QsrjcFd7ikx0CE1N9pgZLEwxoI0IpTWbPh6TECk2bMxL4maTKg%2BaoABxxLh2TCWeRlSHcMtMAAeme47mms1UK1p6tQxm51mUkPkHqaYY97uIwBEOSK8uGBt6dgAwix4hms2ac5K8wXJTXy3XISXa3WKtmuM2OTzbA4vK5VB4XKpd/ZF8vfKus%2BuJZu16WanhIQAWA9MHrY8m27Cxe3sHhaBvO8Hy0J8ly4LgVzfW9kNzfNvzLfBIWLHcQJPM8exsKCULse84KUPBEJfcU0O3DCNywyUgIrKt0LLZA61o5DULfD9VC/RiuL3VRaC4IDCLA89IIcdxYPce9y3kXiUNfBiTy4M0NnmSV8J/djqx/biiJbKZ5ARPk8FELYBQYEQhlQNQankSFLWUEglVjBg1P41dBOEk9RMhWhHCko90OIiDSIcf9FOUwR5FUDyvNUa1Rj8jTNMCliJUAncjM4q0Gyi8zGiYPk9AytUHzwZLMlSNpQnDGdDSy%2BicqYz88uK7jIS4LwIoqJtZNing7ASiqqrDTB6o6zStLNOsSGw4CxII0rGPcdbbyU1RrwXJD1M6iV3k8PoVwRAgkQOjwxQ4YUXCkKsGGkOwpFIFhpC8T7UGked%2BH4RpRHEIYm1oT6CB%2Bl6q26EA7C8AA6dxCwATi4YVC2FNHHDsWg0dRuxGGkf9PpMOgvC8L6YdIf6pE%2BwQQGp6GpF%2Bqs4FgJBlXkVUSnISgeb54gQGAQsuFIZRVWKYgmYgSxacsQpBVkaRIdIZVJwIA4WAYVW2c%2BrBNTYDZafwBFrjwKqmYN0hMDrK0RGKNXPtWTA3qkdXfgiF3XtYdggd4Rh/iZyAqyxGzNGkJI62QCUkhMdxtKSAB1Hz9gOdxGdBiQ6Fe97Pu%2B236brQtHCSRx/2mZA48LJHtIgXBCFWiHIXnVJedqpsuAqQHeH4KGYYZUh4f/NGkccWgvGFLgJK8dx/0LLxJ%2BJj2yZp4vpEZ5nSFZ9n86kLhycp6mi9%2Bumt93oeqyq2XI5Af8gA)

```
// optimize("no-omit-frame-pointer") doesn't seem to work
// we still don't get a frame-point unless we force -O0 for the function with optimize(0)
__attribute__((noinline, noclone, returns_twice, optimize(0)))
int Setjmp(jmp_buf var){
    // relies on the compiler to make a stack-frame
    // because we're using inline asm inside a function instead of at global scope
     __asm__(
             "    mov 8(%ebp), %eax     # get pointer to jmp_buf, passed as argument on stack\n"
             "    mov    %ebx, (%eax)   # jmp_buf[0] = ebx\n"
             "    mov    %esi, 4(%eax)  # jmp_buf[1] = esi\n"
             "    mov    %edi, 8(%eax)  # jmp_buf[2] = edi\n"
             "    mov    (%ebp), %ecx\n"
             "    mov    %ecx, 12(%eax) # jmp_buf[3] = ebp\n"
             "    lea    8(%ebp), %ecx  # get previous value of esp, before call\n"
             "    mov    %ecx, 16(%eax) # jmp_buf[4] = esp before call\n"
             "    mov    4(%ebp), %ecx  # get saved caller eip from top of stack\n"
             "    mov    %ecx, 20(%eax) #jmp_buf[5] = saved eip\n"
             "    xor    %eax, %eax     #eax = 0\n"
     );

    return 0;
}

__attribute__((noinline, noclone, optimize(0)))
void Longjmp(jmp_buf var,int m){
    __asm__("    mov  8(%ebp),%edx # get pointer to jmp_buf, passed as argument 1 on stack\n"
            "    mov  12(%ebp),%eax #get int val in eax, passed as argument 2 on stack\n"
            "    test    %eax,%eax # is int val == 0?\n"
            "    jnz 1f\n"
            "    inc     %eax      # if so, eax++\n"
            "1:\n"
            "    mov   (%edx),%ebx # ebx = jmp_buf[0]\n"
            "    mov  4(%edx),%esi # esi = jmp_buf[1]\n"
            "    mov  8(%edx),%edi #edi = jmp_buf[2]\n"
            "    mov 12(%edx),%ebp # ebp = jmp_buf[3]\n"
            "    mov 16(%edx),%ecx # ecx = jmp_buf[4]\n"
            "    mov     %ecx,%esp # esp = ecx\n"
            "    mov 20(%edx),%ecx # ecx = jmp_buf[5]\n"
            "    jmp *%ecx         # eip = ecx");
}
```

If you used an `asm` statement at global scope, you wouldn't need to fight against the compiler with `__attribute__` stuff to make sure it emits the prologue you expect.  You could also skip setting up EBP so you'd have the caller's EBP directly.

```
asm(".globl SetJmp \n"
    "SetJmp:       \n\t"
    "   push   %ebp  \n\t"
    "   mov    %esp, %ebp  \n\t"

    "...  your current implementation    \n\t"

    "   xor    %eax,%eax   \n\t"
    "   pop    %ebp        \n\t"
    "   ret                \n\t"
 );
```

Comment: Note that depending on OPs compiler configuration, `-fomit-frame-pointer` may or may not be a default option (but it's impossible to tell). `__attribute__((naked))` could possibly help. I'm actually pretty surprised that the compiler doesn't just throw out the assembly as it has no side effects declared, but alas, that might just be the lack of optimizations.

Comment: @Jester thanks for the solution the code works fine. it seems i need to get more information about the stack layout that clang use in different situations. about the inline assembly thing as i said i don't use inline assembly that's my first time to use it i thought it's the right way to implement the functions because as i said i'm not experienced in Assembly and again thank you for helping

Comment: @jacky The stack layout is pretty much unpredictable in all but the simplest situations. Try to avoid inline assembly if possible. It's full of pitfalls, very tricky to use correctly and often there are much better ways to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: @fuz If there are no output operands then GCC assumes the asm statement is volatile and has undeclared side effects.

Comment: @fuz: agreed, this would have broken horribly if compiled at anything other than `-O0`.  Fixed with `__attribute__((noinline, optimize(0)))`, and added an example of putting an `asm` statement at global scope.