# skipping functions in return sequence of callers

Tags: c, function, assembly, x86

In a sequence of function calls, such as

```
                main() --> A() --> B()-->C();
```

when a called function finishes, it normally returns to the calling function, e.g. `C()` returns to `B()`, which returns to `A()`, etc.

i'm wondering if it is also possible to return directly to an earlier function in the calling sequence 
so `C()` return to `main()` and skip `B()` and `A()`

if it is possible how can i do it ? and can you explain how it work and when it used in reality.

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int A(void);
int B(void);
void main(void )
{
    A();
}

int A()
{ 
    printf("enter A()\n");
    B();
    printf("exit A()\n");
}

int B()
{
    printf("enter B()\n");
    printf("exit B()\n");
}
```

and i want to skip return  to function `A()` from `B()` so that the `printf("exit A()\n");`  will not execute  and give me this result:

```
enter A()                                                                                                                  
enter B()                                                                                                                  
exit B()
```

Comment: You can't in C unless you use `setjmp` / `longjmp`.  Or you could have `B()` call `exit()` instead of returning.  If this was C++, you could use try/catch and exception to unwind the stack back to `main()`, if `main` had been compiled to support that (by using `try` / `catch`.

Comment: Why did you tag this x86 assembly? Did you want to have `B()` jmp directly to the end of `main`, regardless where it was called from.  I guess in theory for a specific platform you could unwind the stack and fetch your parent's return address, but that would work differently for Linux vs. Windows, using `.eh_frame` metadata on Linux for example.  It might work some of the time for simple examples.

Comment: Note that `main()` could have been compiled to tail-call A with a `jmp A`, because you declared it `void`.  Also that your program has undefined behaviour: you fall off the end of non-void functions A() and B().  And `void main(void)` is not one of the valid function signatures is ISO C: `int main(void)` is legal.  `void main()` will work on normal compilers for x86, you'll just get a garbage exit status.

Comment: i use intel pc that's why x86 tag

Comment: wow wow the famos @PeterCordes can u check my answer if it is 100% correct please

Comment: I think we might be discussing a XY problem here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem By which I mean that you might get better help if you go one step back and describe what you want to achieve by skipping part of the return path. What do you want to use this mechanism for? If you describe that, it might be achievable in different ways, which are easier to understand and/or more widely used (which means you will learn something which is better reusable for other problems).

Comment: @nora: I meant, why did you tag it assembly at all?  Are you trying to learn about stack layout in assembly, and how compilers implement stuff in practice?  Because going down that road isn't going to give you a safe or portable way to do this.

Comment: what is sense of this question ? are this something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070185/stack-manipulation-in-c-without-using-inline-assembly/41074284#41074284) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before everything check out @PeterCordes is answers the question in more than a way

**okey let's start :**

this type of stuff can be done using something known as `long jump` so  your code after editing will look like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>//c standard library header
jmp_buf env; // for saving longjmp environment
main()
{
    int r, a=100;
    printf("call setjmp to save environment\n");
    if ((r=setjmp(env)) == 0){
        A();
        printf("normal return\n");
    }
    else
        printf("back to main() via long jump, r=%d a=%d\n", r, a);
}
int A()
{ 
    printf("enter A()\n");
    B();
    printf("exit A()\n");
}
int B()
{
    printf("enter B()\n");
    printf("long jump? (y|n) ");
    if (getchar()=='y')
    longjmp(env, 1234);
    printf("exit B()\n");
}
```

**let's understand what just happened**

In the above program, `setjmp()` saves the current execution environment in a `jmp_buf`
structure and `returns 0`.

The program proceeds to call `A()`, which calls `B()`.

While
in the function `B()`, if the user chooses not to return by `long jump`, the functions will
show the normal return sequence.

If the user chooses to return by `longjmp(env,1234)`, 
execution will return to the last saved environment with a `nonzero` value.

In
this case, it causes `B()` to return to `main()` directly, bypassing `A()`.

The principle of
`long jump` is very simple. When a function finishes, it returns by the

`(caller_EIP, caller_EBP)`
in the current stack frame, 
If we replace `(caller_EIP, caller_EBP)` with

`(saved_EIP, saved_EBP)` of an earlier function
in the calling sequence, execution would return to that function directly.

In addition
to the `(saved_EIP, saved_EBP)`, `setjmp()` may also save CPU’s general registers and the
original `ESP`, so that `longjmp()` can restore the complete environment of the returned
function.

Long jump can be used to abort a function in a calling sequence, causing
execution to resume from a known environment saved earlier.

Although rarely used
in user mode programs, it is a common technique in systems programming.

For example,
it may be used in a signal catcher to bypass a user mode function that caused
an exception or trap error.

you can check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/longjmp/) is also good

Comment: i will try it and let you know the result

Comment: `-fomit-frame-pointer` is on by default, so `longjmp` can't assume there's a linked-list of saved-EBP/return-address.  I don't think `longjmp` has to actually unwind the stack at all, it just jumps to an address saved in the `jmp_buf`, and restores `ESP`/`RSP` and other call-preserved registers from the `jmp_buf`.  So it's not like an exception unwinding the stack looking for the first catch block that can handle it.  `longjmp` has a specific `jmp_buf` as its destination.  See [setjmp and longjmp implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46094444) for how it could be implemented.

Comment: you of course wrong describe how setjump/longjump work. setjum save nonvolatile registers (and possible os specific data, like SEH frame on windows x86) and longjump restore context (and possible do some os specific, `RtlUnwind` on x86 windows)